# Unable to compile CGAL example Triangulation_2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt5, visual-studio-2019, cgal

I have installed `CGAL` with `vcpkg`. Also installed `Qt5` with `vcpgk`. Then I have dowloaded `CGAL-5.0-examples` and ran `cmake-gui ..`. It did without errors. Qt5 variables appeared to point to some places inside `vcpkg`. Unfortunately, after `sln` is genereted and I am opening it, I can't build it:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.lib' for_loop_2  D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\LINK 1       
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: 'D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_CGAL.cpp': No such file or directory   CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources  D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\c1xx 1       
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: 'D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_Input.cpp': No such file or directory  CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources  D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\c1xx 1       
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: 'D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_File.cpp': No such file or directory   CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources  D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\c1xx 1       
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: 'D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\qrc_Triangulation_2.cpp': No such file or directory    CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources  D:\dev\CGAL-5.0\examples\Triangulation_2\build\c1xx 1
```

Why is it trying to open `cpp` files from build directory, although source directory is one level up?

[image]

Comment: Did you check that page ? https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html#ssec-vcpkg-compile-example

More specifically, did you check the coherency between x86 and x64 configurations ? Default for cmake vcpkg config is 32bit, so if you try to compile the code with visual in 64bits there is a good chance you will run into  errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install cgal[qt] for examples that use Qt5 : 
`vcpkg install cgal[qt]`
This contains specific headers for most 3D examples and demos used by CGAL.

Also there is a specificity when using vcpkg with cmake, because the default behavior for `Optional Platform` is x64 in cmake, but x86 in vcpkg. it means that if you leave it empty, everything that comes from outside vcpkg will be x64, and everything inside vcpkg x86, and you will run into warnings, link errors and probably some build errors too. [This page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html#ssec-vcpkg-compile-example) explains the steps to configure and build an example of CGAL with vcpg.